# Why is there a run time error for this code?

Tags: c++

If I comment `i++` in if loop the while loop shall run and at least print `0,1,2,3`. But, instead, it outputs the runtime exceeded in C++ Shell. I didn't understand why?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
    
int main() {
   int i = 0;
   while (i < 10) {
     if (i == 4) {
     //   i++;
       continue;
     }
     cout << i << "\n";
     i++;
   } 
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like whatever online IDE you're using waits for the program to exit before it shows you the output, and if it runs forever it doesn't show you any output. Could also be output buffering.

Comment: Move `cout << i << "\n";` before the `if` and watch what happens.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. In particular, what exactly is the output? Copy'n'paste the text here. Also, which "C++ shell" are you using?

Comment: What happens to `i` when `i == 4`? Look like the scenery never changes after that point? (or you end up chasing your tail -- pick your metaphor...) This is also the perfect error to learn how to use a debugger with. Watch the value of `i` as your code executes. That will disclose the issue. See [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Change `cout << i << "\n";` to `cout << i << endl;` and you should see some output but you will still have the infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

The [continue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/continue) statement causes a jump, as if by goto to the end of the loop body, skipping the `i++` causing an infinite loop as i stays 4.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `break` instead of `continue`, then the machine will understand that the loop needs to be exited at `i == 4`.

Do something like:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    int i = 0;

    while (i < 10) {
        if (i == 4) break;

        std::cout << i << std::endl;
        i++;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Also, notice that the While loop won't iterate till 10 since we've set a break statement when `i == 4` is met.

Comment: It is unclear whether OP is trying to print `0 1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9`  or just `0 1 2 3`

Comment: A little bit clearance is given - *if loop the while loop shall run and at least print 0,1,2,3*.